# How can I change the author / user name used in GitHub pull requests?

Tags: github

GitHub seems to use the public profile name as git `user.name` in web operations, like when merging pull requests.

Is there no way to use a different user name per repository, or at least for an organization?

We have set up our `.gitconfig` files to have consistent author info and are annoyed by pull request merge commits, which do not use the author info specified in the config. We don't want to force every developer to change their public profile name to be "firstname lastname" or so.

Apparently it's either that or having to live with inconsistent author names (not mails) in commits...